# TRAMP cannot edit file I have access to with ssh

Tags: ssh, permissions, group, tramp

I have a remote server with a folder owned by root and a group. The group have write permissions and my user is in the group.

However, when I attempt to edit a file with /ssh:user@server:/folder/file and save it, it told me the file was write-protected and attemts to edit the file with /sudo:root@server:/folder/file.

While this does work, I am concerned about this since this really shouldn't happen.

Using ssh and nano on the remote server simply works. I don't really get why the tramp one was failing......

Using /sshfs:user@server:/folder and then navigating to the file works.

However, this prevents me from using ssh after that, e.g. When I'm editing some files with root permissions with /ssh:user@server|sudo::/etc/somefile, it seems that it tried to go through the open sshfs route and told me that sshfs does not support this.

Also, I've tried sg with /ssh:user@server|sg:group@server:/file, which failed in a variety of ways.